# Setting up Chrome tools debugging with Parcel v2 and WebStorm

Tags: typescript, intellij-idea, google-chrome-devtools, webstorm, parcel

I just started a project from boilerplate that I found and can't seem to get the debugger to hit my breakpoints in WebStorm. I am using `parcel v2` with TypeScript and WebStorm debugger.

Here's my package json:

```
{
  "name": "phaser3-typescript-parcel2-boilerplate",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A boilerplate for Phaser 3 using Parceljs v2",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "parcel serve ./src/index.html -p 8000",
    "build": "rimraf dist && parcel build ./src/index.html --dist-dir dist",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "lint": "eslint ./src --ext .js,.jsx,.ts,.tsx"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/sinxwal/phaser3-typescript-parcel2-boilerplate.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "phaser",
    "phaser3",
    "parcel",
    "parcel2",
    "typescript",
    "linter",
    "eslint",
    "prettier",
    "boilerplate",
    "template",
    "starter"
  ],
  "author": "sinxwal",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/sinxwal/phaser3-typescript-parcel2-boilerplate/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/sinxwal/phaser3-typescript-parcel2-boilerplate#readme",
  "browserslist": [
    "> 0.2%",
    "not dead"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@parcel/packager-raw-url": "2.1.1",
    "@parcel/transformer-image": "2.1.1",
    "@parcel/transformer-typescript-tsc": "2.1.1",
    "@parcel/transformer-webmanifest": "2.1.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "5.9.0",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "5.9.0",
    "eslint": "8.6.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "4.0.0",
    "parcel": "2.1.1",
    "parcel-reporter-static-files-copy": "1.3.4",
    "prettier": "2.5.1",
    "rimraf": "3.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.5.4"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "phaser": "3.55.2",
    "workbox-core": "6.4.2",
    "workbox-precaching": "6.4.2",
    "workbox-routing": "6.4.2",
    "workbox-strategies": "6.4.2"
  },
  "staticFiles": {
    "staticPath": "public",
    "staticOutPath": "assets"
  }
}
```

According to [parcel's](https://parceljs.org/recipes/debugging/) documentation on setting up the debugger I simply must have a `launch.json` with the proper configuration. Do I need a `package.json` and a `launch.json` in the same project? Does running `parcel serve` work the same as the entry command? The documentation is a bit sparse for people who are new to JavaScript land.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need `launch.json` unless you try debugging it with VSCode;
for WebStorm, you have to create a [JavaScript Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/webstorm/2021.3/run-debug-configuration-javascript-debug.html) run configuration with your application URL (`http://localhost:8000`, or whatever URL you use to access your application in browser) and then press **Debug**. Assuming that source maps are enabled, no extra configuration is required